# Why am I getting errors on all my cshtml files when using Html Helpers in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code I'm getting errors on all of my `.cshtml` files where I use Html helpers.

```
@using System.Web.Mvc

@Model IEnumerable<storedprocedrure.PersonalInfo>

@{ Layout = null; }
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/> <title>PersonalInfoList</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") </p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> @Html.ActionLink(model => model.OperationTypeId) </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName) </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CNIC) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MobileNo) </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentAddress) </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PermanentAddress) </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email) </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City) </th> 
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OperationTypeId) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNIC) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobileNo) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentAddress) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PermanentAddress) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email) </td> 
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City) </td> 
            <td> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonalInfoID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PersonalInfoID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonalInfoID }) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
</body>
```

I tried to create a new file and still its showing me errors then I tried to use `@using System.Web.Mvc` it's still showing errors, and even my code is not running when try debug and open in chrome on first page it shows errors on html helpers

Comment: could you provide the error message?